# Why does Bitcoin Core store the block height and the time of each transaction in the memory pool?

Tags: unconfirmed-transactions, mempool, memory

...given that one can be derived from the other? Surely the unsigned integer of height would be sufficient without the addition uint64_t of the time (to the second), wouldn't it?

Comment: I don't see how one can be computed from the other, in either direction. Entry time has higher accuracy than blocks, and Bitcoin Core doesn't have a log of what the height of our active chain was at every local timestamp.

Comment: well, it  easily could - and it would take up less memory than storing the entry height for every single tx in the mempool

or why not use the timestamp in the block index?

Comment: We care about the actual time, not the time that miners choose to put in block headers (which may be up to 2 hours in the future, or roughly an hour in the paat)

Comment: ah, fair point, well, in that case the time could be stored in the mempool, and the height could be derived from that - one entry of height per block, rather than per mempool entry